# Undo drawing image editor android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap, android-canvas

for my app I am creating an image editor which currently works fine but I want to implement un undo button which basically goes back to the previous state of the image. I am trying to do this by using an ArrayList of bitmaps. At first I use this code to open an image from gallery and set canvas:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
            alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp
                    .getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());


            int x = alteredBitmap.getWidth();
            int y = alteredBitmap.getHeight();
            if (x > y) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                lscape = true;
            } else {
                lscape = false;
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            width = size.x;
            height = size.y;
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
            Cursor cur = managedQuery(imageFileUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
            int orientation = -1;
            if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
                orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
            }
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation!=90) {
                matrix.postRotate(orientation);
                scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(alteredBitmap, width, height, false);
                canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);
                choosenImage.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
                choosenImage.setOnTouchListener(this);
                b.add(scaledBitmap);
            }
```

At some point of code I use this to draw a straight line:

```
int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                downx = event.getX();
                downy = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                upx = event.getX();
                upy = event.getY();
                canvas.drawLine(getScaledWidth(downx, width, choosenImage.getWidth()), downy / choosenImage.getHeight() * height, getScaledWidth(upx, width, choosenImage.getWidth()), upy / choosenImage.getHeight() * height, paint);
                choosenImage.invalidate();
                b.add(scaledBitmap);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Now what should I write for my onclick on undo button? I've tried everything but dont know how to reset the canvas to display one of the bitmaps saved in the arraylist...dont know if its a problem with my way of setting the canvas to the bitmaps or if im missing something. This was my latest attempt:

```
scaledBitmap = b.get(b.size()-2);
            b.remove(b.size() - 1);
            choosenImage.invalidate();
```

Im new to android development so sorry if I'm not being clear, but really any help would be greatly appreciated I am stuck in this project and it is due in soon.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**List of bitmaps --> Out of memory!**

Bitmaps are kept in a very limited area of memory and having a whole list of fullscreen bitmaps for und purposes will make your app go out of memory very quickly.

**List of paths --> Better**

What I did for my (very old) app "[Fingercolors](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=panama.android.fingercolors)", is keeping a list of all paths the user paints. The paths consist of a list of points and some information about color, stroke-width etc.

For undoing a step, I start (offscreen) with an empty bitmap and repaint all paths from the list *except for the last one* and then show that rebuilt bitmap.

This allows unlimited undo and also redo and it is fast enough even for complex images with lots of paths.